# esxi 6.0 nfs mounted share is not visible and not unmountable yet still tries to mount

Tags: vmware-esxi, nfs

I have a NAS that is presenting shares via NFS for esxi hosts, one is called metro-software which is where all of my ISOs and installation media resides.

I recently went through a lab reconfiguration to 10gbit and rebooted the esxi host and now it's trying to mount on the old IP however my NAS is blocking it. I can't figure out where in esxi its storing this mount information to try and mount it.

the vsphere c# client doesnt show it, nor does the ssh command `esxvfg-volume -l`

Any tips on forcing the removal of it?

```
[root@phxlp-esx02:/vmfs/volumes] esxcfg-volume -l

[root@phxlp-esx02:/vmfs/volumes] esxcfg-volume -u metro-software
VmFileSystem: Unable to get device properties for volume / device : Can't    umount normal VMFS volumes. This option is only valid for snapshot/replica   volumes which are manually mounted.

[root@phxlp-esx02:/vmfs/volumes] esxcfg-volume -m metro-software
No matching volume metro-software found!
```

**NAS logs are**

```
Dec 23 07:15:47 stg02 mountd[3340]: mount request denied from 192.168.30.51 for /mnt/VAULT/software
```

the temporary workaround is to allow the `192.168.30.51` IP so it can be mounted but it still doesn't solve my problem of how/where esxi stores its mount information similar to `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 1):

to answer my own question... this is how I resolved it.

The issue was three fold

1. I didn't do a cleanup of the vcenter server 6.5 installation so the datastore was in a cluster with i/o controls and the esxi host was still configured for this. I couldn't remove the datastore because of this.
2. esxi couldn't mount it because of the IP not being on the exports list on my NAS
3. finally once it was re-mounted, esxi still thought it was being used

running via ssh `esxcli storage nfs list` showed me the mount point, however trying to remove it via `esxcli storage nfs remove -v metro-software` would fail because it thought it was still being used, even though it wasn't.

What I did was allow the IP to mount the share, so it showed in the gui once it mounted. However I couldn't unmount it, so I then removed the IP from the whitelist and then went into the GUI and unmounted it.I could also have re-ran `esxcli storage nfs remove -v metro-software` instead.